# C# swap in Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my Control.When I change the properties of the control. I get this:

```
 this.myLabel1.BorderShadow = true;
 this.myLabel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

And I need to get this:

```
   this.myLabel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
   this.myLabel1.BorderShadow = true;
```

How to do so is done automatically in Form.Desinger.cs ? 
If you say Why?

```
 private bool BorderShadow_ = false;
    public bool BorderShadow
    {
        get
        {
            return BorderShadow_;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Border_Style_ == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
            {
                BorderShadow_ = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("BorderShadow", "BorderShadow can be true if BorderStyle=FixedSingle");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the difference in `what you want` and `what you are getting` ??

Comment: Swap in Desinger property.

Comment: What is the point of doing this? Why not just ignore `BorderShadow` if `BorderStyle` is not set to `BorderStyle.FixedSingle`?

Comment: @AndrewSun it's different.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into the [`ISupportInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx) interface. It allows you to skip the validity check when initializing your controls. For example (adapted from one of my projects):

```
public class MyControl : Control, ISupportInitialize
{
    private bool _created = true;

    public void BeginInit()
    {
        _created = false;
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        _created = true;
        //check all your properties here too
    }

    private bool BorderShadow_ = false;
    public bool BorderShadow
    {
        get
        {
            return BorderShadow_;
        }
        set
        {
            BorderShadow_ = value;
            if (_created && Border_Style_ != BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, the VS designer will automatically add calls to `BeginInit` and `EndInit` for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think they will appears in the same order as they are defined. So you can override with `new` old setting:

```
public new BorderStyle BorderStyle
{
    get {return base.BorderStyle;}
    set {base.BorderStyle = value;}
}
```

and then declare your `BorderShadow` setting.

Answer (score 0):

The designer will always order the properties alphabetically and this can't be changed.

The sense of a property is that it is *side effect free* and that it can be changed at any time in any order. This means that if you have multiple properties which representing some kind of complex state and not all combinations are making sense, this error should not be reported while switching the property itself.

So to accomplish these problems you have two possibilities:

1. Like @Andrew already mentioned implement `ISupportInitialize` and take care if you are within this state.
2. Within the property setter call a method that checks if all settings currently made are making sense and perform the desired action only in this case:

   ```
   public class MyControl : Control
   {
       private bool _BorderShadow;
       private BorderStyle _BorderStyle;

       public bool BorderShadow
       {
           get { return _BorderShadow; }
           set
           {
               if(_BorderShadow != value)
               {
                   _BordeShadow = value;
                   ApplyBorderShadowIfNeeded();
               }
           }
       }

       public BorderStyle BorderStyle
       {
           get { return _BorderStyle; }
           set
           {
               if(_BorderStyle != value)
               {
                   _BorderStyle = value;
                   ApplyBorderShadowIfNeeded();
               }
           }
       }

       private void ApplyBorderShadowIfNeeded()
       {
            if(_BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle
               && _BorderShadow)
            {
                 // ToDo: Apply the shadow to the border.
            }
       }
   }
   ```